# Contar registros donde valor sea menor o igual a 0 en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

muy buenas tardes.

Como hago para contar registros dentro de un if?
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$termi=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `recibir_items` GROUP BY codigo_reci ORDER BY codigo_reci");
    while($traterm = mysqli_fetch_array($termi)){
    
    if ($traterm['canti_recibidos']<=0){
        
        
    }else{
    
    
    }
```

La idea es que si la variable canti_recibidos es menor o igual a 0 entonces debe contarla.
Como podría hacer eso?

Cualquier ayuda me podría servir de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una variable inicializada en 0 y le vas acumulando en el if que es cuando se cumple la condición

Comment: Con `$contador++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dicen los compañeros en comentarios, sólo necesitas declarar una variable que sirva de contador, antes del bucle, e irla incrementando cuando la condición se cumpla.

Por ejemplo:

```
$termi=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `recibir_items` GROUP BY codigo_reci ORDER BY codigo_reci");
$mTotal=0;
while($traterm = mysqli_fetch_array($termi)){
    if ($traterm['canti_recibidos']<=0){
        $mTotal++;
    } else {
        //Lo que haya que hacer y si no hay que hacer nada no pongas else
    }    
}
//Usar $mTotal
```

Si solamente interesa ese dato, podrías hacerlo directamente en la consulta. De este modo optimizarías en la base de datos y traerías solamente el valor ya sumado.

```
/*
  De necesitarse SOLO ese dato 
  no tendrían sentido ni el GROUP BY ni el ORDER BY
*/

$sql="SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `canti_recibidos` <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total FROM `recibir_items`";

$termi=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$mData=mysqli_fetch_assoc($termi);
$mTotal=$mData['total'];
#Usar $mTotal
```